# How to pass multiple checkboxes to PHP through JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery

I HAVE modified my code, i used firebug console.log to detect weather the the php  gets the array passed or not. and firebug displays this - rescheck[]=2&rescheck=1&rescheck=3

I think php gets the array if THATS what an array in php supposed to be like.

SO guys, if thats correct how to insert that array in database? or how to loop it? the foreach loop ive made didnt work.

JQUERY CODE:

```
$('#res-button').click(function (){

var room_id=$('[name=rescheck[]]:checked').serialize().replace(/%5B%5D/g,'[]');

    alert(room_id);


  $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "reservation-valid.php",
                    data: {name_r:name_r, email_r:email_r,contact_r:contact_r,prop_id:p_id,cvalue:room_id},
                    success: function(data) {

                    console.log(data);
}

});
});

<input type="checkbox" name="rescheck[]" value="<?php echo $roomid; ?>"  />
```

PHP CODE:

```
$c_array=$_POST['cvalue'];

    echo $c_array;

    //foreach($c_array as $ch)
    //{
    //$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservation VALUES('','$prop_id','$ch','$name_r','$contact_r','$email_r','')");
    //}
```

I think I managed my jquery code to be right, but I don't know how to fetch that with PHP.

Comment: @user, I've edited your question in order to make it a little bit better. Please stop undoing my edits for no reason.

Comment: i didnt undo your edits. i dont even know how to undo

Comment: @Charlie Pigarelli Easy, Tiger. Looks like he was probably in the middle of editing his code when you submitted your update.

Comment: @Wiseguy, oh. Could be. Than @user, i'm sorry for my aggressive behavior.

Comment: no problem man. but can you please help me instead? :D

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do ibn my site for saving to a db a list of checkboxes with jquery and ajax call. It make an array and pass it to the ajax call and the php script handle the array.
If you get any error here you should debug the js array with firebug for be sure that is formed correctly.

js script:

```
var $checkBox = $('[name=rescheck[]]:checked');
$checkBox.each(function() {
   if ($(this).is(":checked")){
        valuesCheck[this.value] = 1;
    }else{
        valuesCheck[this.value] = 0;    
   }
```

and the PHP script:

```
$checkTab = $_POST['cvalue'];
        foreach ($checkTab as $idChkTab => $checkedOrNot){
            if ($checkedOrNot== "0"){
                //do something if isn't checked
            }
```

Comment: i saved it $c_array=$_POST['cvalue'];

Comment: sorry didn't see it.look at my other answer I think we get it:)

Answer (score 0):

room_id is an array, so if you want to get the value for each, you need to get all value together first.

```
var room_id_string = '';

for(i=0;i<room_id.length;i++){
    room_id_string += room_id.eq(i).val() + ',';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your below code will only pass Array jquery object of `[name=rescheck[]]:checked` to `room_id`

Instead of this you will have to create a array and push values in it like this

```
var room_id = Array();

$('[name=rescheck[]]:checked').each(function(){
      room_id.push($(this).val());

});
```

Comment: how would i make my php code to fetch the array? and please check my modified code above

Comment: man. i tried your code, its ok in jquery. i alerted the room_id and it displays all the ids. but when i check in the php( thats when the jquery arrray is passed), i used console.log to see weather the array is really passed, but the only thing that is passed is the last value of the array.

Comment: just before making the ajax call log the room_id in console and see do you get an array???

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery it might be easier for you to just use the serialize function to get all the form data. jQuery passes the form to the server so you don't have to worry about getting all the values. If you use it in conjunction with the validate plugin you might find it a little easier!

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: can you show me how to use the serialize and what is its use?

Comment: In your ajax change the line "data: {...}," to "data: $("#formId").serialize()," where formId is the id of the form (or you could use a reference to the form if stored in a variable previously. That should get all the information from the form and create the object to pass to the server

Comment: i dont use forms. can i still use serialize? i get all the data one by one and store it in var. can i serialize it all? if yes can you please provide example? please

Comment: and i cant replace "data:{...}" with "data:$().serialize()" since im passing multiple variables to a php page. i am not only passing the checkbox value

Comment: Let me ask you a question then... why do you not use forms? Forms are the one method of user interaction to gain information. If you're not using a form how are you getting the information from a user? Might be worth wrapping the inputs into a form in order to use the serialize function

Comment: Serialize will serialize EVERYTHING in your form... if you had one

Comment: cause when i wrap my code with forms the tables and divs will break their positions. i dont know why.