# How to fetch serialized jquery array to a php page?

Tags: php, jquery

heres my code ive serialized checboxes and i want it to be pass to a php page through ajax. NOTE that i am not using forms. and i cant use forms. i am using click event on a button to pass the value.

```
$('#res-button').click(function (){
    var pid = $('#pid');
    var name_res= $('#name_res');
    var email_res= $('#email_res');
    var contact_res= $('#contact_res');
    var room_id=$('[name=rescheck[]]:checked').serialize().replace(/%5B%5D/g,'[]');

    alert(room_id);

$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "reservation-valid.php",
                    data: {name_r:name_r, email_r:email_r,contact_r:contact_r,prop_id:p_id,cvalue:room_id},
                    success: function(data) {
                    //some codes here
                    });

                    }
                }); 
});
```

THE RESULT OF MY ALERT TO room_id is this- "rescheck[]=1&rescheck[]=2&....." so i know my serialize is working, but i cant get it to php to insert my ids in database.

this is my php code:

```
$c_array=$_POST['cvalue'];

    foreach($c_array as $ch)
    {
    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservation VALUES('','$prop_id','$ch','$name_r','$contact_r','$email_r','')");
    }
```

Comment: this is the same post as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220293/how-to-pass-multiple-checkboxes-to-php-through-jquery

Answer (score 0):

change your js:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "reservation-valid.php",
                    data: {'name_r':name_r, 'email_r':email_r,'contact_r':contact_r,'prop_id':p_id,'cvalue':room_id},
                    success: function(data) {
                    //some codes here
                    });

                    }
                });
```

your names of the values are being overrided

Comment: ive changed it like you said, put ' ' in the data variables. but its not working still. any other idea?

Comment: i think the php page is not getting an array from the jquery, since its not performing the foreach loop. but i dont know what to do anymore.

Comment: try echoing the post: print_($_POST) to see what it has gotten

Comment: i cant echo the php code since it has no UI. the php code above is the only code i have in my reservation-valid.php. you know how to echo it in other page?

Comment: on the succes part just console.log(data). and put the print in ur php and the console will get the returns

Comment: dude. how to view the console.log? where to find it? i clicked tools firebug tracing, but its empty. where to view console logs?

Comment: i have a firebug error console? is it the right one? if it is then it doesnt show anything after i put console.log(data);

Comment: figure it out. i think im done now. yes the firbug console. edit your original post with the results

Comment: i have figure it out now. it display in the console log rescheck[]=1 .. something like that. but i messed up the console again. and it only shows now cant remember site in private browsing somthing like that.

Comment: dude. heres my screenshot on the console.log report. http://i.imgur.com/SoqYe.png . you can see the php gets exactly what the room_id passed. any idea how to modify that to be an array?

Comment: did u do print_r($_POST) and console.log(data)? in the success

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a JSON approach using [serializeArray](http://jsfiddle.net/JuanToroMarty/ebFzT/)

in php you should use JSON_DECODE to receive the data from the $.ajax call

pd: Sorry for my english.